Numerical calculation of the Electric field in a system knowing the potentials on the contour
I have a problem in numerically determining the electric field lines given the potential in a system described in the photo. The electric field vector E is related to the potential at a point with the opposite of the gradient of the potential at the point. I have approximated the derivatives in a known way but in the graph I do not see the orthogonality. Could someone suggest me a refinement thanks.

